# Is this a possible sub query with standard SQL

Tags: sql, database

Is it possible to run one query and get resultset A that's sorted by an age field desc,
then query result A for any records that have, lets say a color field that equals 5
AND among that group with matching fields, sort them by the height column desc 
And return all of the results at one time:

so data might look like this:

```
age color height
4    5     7
3    6     1
2    9     2 
6    5     3
```

output of 1st part would yield (sorted by age)

```
age color height
6    5     1
4    5     7
3    6     2
2    9     3
```

output of final part of query would yield (subset with equal color, sorted by height):

```
age color height
4    5     7
6    5     1
3    6     2
2    9     3
```

Comment: Your description doesn't seem to match your example (the age desc doesn't seem to have anything to do with the end result). Why sort by age at all in the first place?

Comment: @Bruno - Apparently, the order by `age` should be descending only if there is different colors, for the same ones, it must be order by `height`. I know, confusing

Comment: @Lamak, I think I understand what you mean, but the example was a bit confusing. Still not sure how you get from the first set of rows to the second. Where does 6 5 1 come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is a bit confusing, because you can easily achieve the same result by using `ORDER BY color, height DESC`  (there seems to be too few rows).

As far as I understand your question, you're actually interested in sorting per decreasing `age` first anyway, but you also want to reorder the set of rows that have the same `color` value, if they're contiguous when sorted by age.

You might be able to achieve what you want by using [window functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_%28SQL%29#Window_function) (more specifically by partitionning the results). This should be ["standard" SQL (SQL:2003)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003), although it won't be supported by all SQL RDMBS (in particular not by MySQL, as far as I know).

Here is a working example with [PostgreSQL (8.4 or above)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
    age INTEGER,
    color INTEGER,
    height INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO test_table(age, color, height) VALUES (7, 10, 1);
INSERT INTO test_table(age, color, height) VALUES (6, 5, 1);
INSERT INTO test_table(age, color, height) VALUES (5, 5, 10);
INSERT INTO test_table(age, color, height) VALUES (4, 5, 7);
INSERT INTO test_table(age, color, height) VALUES (3, 6, 2);
INSERT INTO test_table(age, color, height) VALUES (2, 9, 3);
```

Query (see [SQL Fiddle for live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c18ff/1/0)):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT age, color, height,
           max(age) OVER (PARTITION BY color ORDER BY age DESC, color DESC)
               AS maxage
        FROM test_table
)
SELECT age, color, height FROM cte
    ORDER BY maxage DESC, color, height;
```

Results:

```
 age | color | height 
-----+-------+--------
   7 |    10 |      1
   6 |     5 |      1
   4 |     5 |      7
   5 |     5 |     10
   3 |     6 |      2
   2 |     9 |      3
```

What this does is that the window function allocates the max of `age` as `maxage` to all the rows within the partition (partitioned by `color`) when ordered by `age` and `color` initially.

The result of the CTE (it could be a sub-select) is this (see [SQL Fiddle for live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c18ff/2/0)):

```
 age | color | height | maxage 
-----+-------+--------+--------
   7 |    10 |      1 |      7
   2 |     9 |      3 |      2
   3 |     6 |      2 |      3
   6 |     5 |      1 |      6
   5 |     5 |     10 |      6
   4 |     5 |      7 |      6
```

Here, every row in the `color` parition has the same `maxage`, which, when ordered by in the final result, also preserves the order of `age`, but allows you to re-order by `height` instead.

(Quick tests in SQL Fiddle seem to indicate this works fine with MS SQL Server 2012 and Oracle 11g R2 too; SQL Server 2008 doesn't seem to like `MAX` and `ORDER BY` in the window definition.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adjusting the criteria used for the order by.

```
select t1.*
from t1
order by (case when color = 5 then height end) desc,
         (case when coalesce(color, 0) <> 5 then age end) desc
```

This sorts first by height descending, among the group where color = 5.  It then sorts by age, among those where color is not 5.  The coalesce just takes care of NULL values.

Be cautioned that the following does not work:

```
order by (case when color = 5 then height else age end) desc
```

This conflates height and age, and the values could overlap.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a sub query - you can use secondary (and tertiary etc...) sorts directly.

```
SELECT age, color, height
FROM table
ORDER BY color, height DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify a secondary search key to get this behaviour:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY color, height DESC
```

will produce:

```
age color height
4    5     7
6    5     1
3    6     2
2    9     3
```

Comment: But in this case the order of the column `age` is correct only by coincidence, not forced